# jQuery swipe with Snap svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, snap.svg

The following code gives the alert and shows in the console, but it doesn't call the function - why could this be?

```
            $('.eventSliderClass').on("swipe",function(event){
            infoRectClick();
            console.log('swiped!');
            alert("Swiped!");
        });

var infoRectClick = function() {
            eventSlider.attr('display', '');
            eventSliderContent.animate({'transform' : 't0,0'}, 250);
        };
```

Also is there any reason why I can't seem to retrieve the id from a var and had to create a class?

Comment: maybe the infoRectClick() funcion definition might help?

Comment: Are you defining `eventSlider` and `eventSliderContent`? maybe replacing them with `$(this)` could help.